# How to get the card number from braintree payments?

Tags: ios, swift4, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I am using braintree pod for my project and it is working nicely after getting nonce. But I want to retrieve the card icon and digits of the card number.

How can I get both card icon in an imageView and card number in UILabel?

I used two pod files.

```
pod 'BraintreeDropIn'
pod 'BraintreeDropIn/UIKit'
```

and I am using this function provided from braintree documentation.

```
func showDropIn(clientTokenOrTokenizationKey: String) {
        let request =  BTDropInRequest()

        //BTUIKAppearance.darkTheme()
        //BTUIKAppearance.sharedInstance().primaryTextColor = UIColor.green

        let dropIn = BTDropInController(authorization: clientTokenOrTokenizationKey, request: request)
        { (controller, result, error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("ERROR : \(error.debugDescription)")
            } else if (result?.isCancelled == true) {
                print("CANCELLED")
            } else if let result = result {
                // Use the BTDropInResult properties to update your UI
                //result.paymentOptionType
                //result.paymentMethod
                //result.paymentIcon
                //result.paymentDescription

                if let outPut = result.paymentMethod {
                    print("\nNonce : \(outPut.nonce)")

                    self.paymentNonce = outPut.nonce
                    self.paymentCardType = result.paymentDescription.description

                }
            }
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        self.present(dropIn!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Right now, Braintree's iOS SDK does not return the card brand icon in the result. However, an image URL is returned in a [transaction response object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/) that contains the card brand icon within the [`imageUrl`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/php#credit_card_details.image_url) attribute. You can check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/popmedic/e79760aa65504085ede282cf868bfc82) on how to display image URLs in Swift. Alternatively, the [`type`](https://braintree.github.io/braintree_ios/Classes/BTPaymentMethodNonce.html#/c:objc(cs)BTPaymentMethodNonce(im)initWithNonce:localizedDescription:type:) is available on the client when the nonce is returned.

For PCI compliance reasons, the full card number is not ever exposed to a merchant if you are using the Drop-in UI. Instead, the iOS SDK will provide the [`lastTwo`](https://braintree.github.io/braintree_ios/Classes/BTCardNonce.html#/c:objc(cs)BTCardNonce(py)lastTwo) digits if you cast the payment method to `BTCardNonce`. [Swift's documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html) has a lot of good info on casting. Though Objective-C, an example would be:

```
BTCardNonce *cardNonce = (BTCardNonce*)result.paymentMethod;
```

Alternatively, you can get a [`maskedNumber`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/transaction/php#credit_card_details.masked_number) from the transaction response object, similarly to the image URL.

<sub>Edited: updated link for adding image URL to Swift 4</sub>

Comment: How can I get it(an image URL is returned in a transaction response object ) in swift4?

Comment: the iOS SDK will provide the last two digits if you cast the result to BTCardNonce - but how?? can you give me exact documentation or code snippets?

Comment: Sorry about that: I meant to cast the payment method to `BTCardNonce`. I've updated my answer with that and a link to use an image URL in Swift. The link sends you to Swift 3 documentation, so if anyone finds Swift 4, that'd be great!

Comment: here is a gist on how to load an image from a remote URL in Swift 4.  https://gist.github.com/popmedic/e79760aa65504085ede282cf868bfc82

Comment: Can I get the imageUrl of Card Icon when nonce is returned?

Comment: No- as stated in the answer, the iOS SDK does not return a card brand icon. Only the transaction response object. I think for some of these more non-code related questions, you should reach out to Braintree's Technical Support at https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact